# How to query a table join where cross-validation from output is simplified?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to produce a table that reveals which instructors are teaching courses that they are not certified to teach.

I have two tables of data:

**certification**

| instructor_id | subject_cert |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 01 |
| 01 | 02 |
| 01 | 03 |
| 03 | 04 |
| 03 | 05 |
| 03 | 06 |
| 05 | 07 |
| 05 | 08 |
| 05 | 09 |

**taught_courses**

| instructor | subject_taught |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 01 |
| 01 | 02 |
| 01 | 05 |
| 03 | 04 |
| 03 | 08 |
| 05 | 07 |

I was thinking about producing a table that looks like this (I'm sure there are alternative options):

| instructor | subject_taught | subject_cert |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 05 | null |
| 03 | 08 | null |

Here's my current code, which produces a table with too many rows, making cross-validation for subject_taught with subject_cert tedious:

```
SELECT
    t.instructor,
    t.subject_taught,
    c.subject_cert
FROM taught_course AS t
LEFT JOIN certification AS c
    ON t.instructor = c.instructor_id
ORDER BY
    t.instructor,
    t.subject_taught,
    c.subject_cert ASC;
```

What suggestions would you have? Any help will be sincerely appreciated, thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
SELECT
    t.instructor,
    t.subject_taught,
    c.subject_cert
FROM taught_course AS t
LEFT JOIN certification AS c
    ON t.instructor = c.instructor_id AND t.subject_taught = c.subject_cert
WHERE c.instructor_id IS NULL
ORDER BY
    t.instructor,
    t.subject_taught,
    c.subject_cert ASC;
```

This is your query, but I added a second condition (`AND t.subject_taught = c.subject_cert`) to the join since you want to match the subjects as well as the instructors and I added `WHERE c.instructor_id IS NULL` since you only want to return rows where the left join failed to find a match.